# ajax not able to capture response from Node Express in multer

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express, multer

I am using multer to upload image and it works great, I am able to see the data getting printed to console, but I am not sure how to capture this data and manipulate it in browser. Below is my code:

```
var multer = require("multer");
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function(req, file, callback){
        callback(null, 'uploads'); // set the destination
    },
    filename: function(req, file, callback){
        callback(null, 'FILE1' + '.jpg'); // set the file name and extension
    }
});
var upload = multer({storage: storage});
app.post('/', upload.any(), function(req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.files);
    var image = req.files;
    console.log(image);
    res.send(image); //this should come to jquery response object in browser, but not sure why it is not
});
```

and below is my jquery code that should be able to get above data in response object:

```
$('body').on('click', '#uploadFile', function (event) {

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/',
                success: function (response) { //this is always "" not sure why, I am expecting multer response to be here
                    console.log('successfully uploaded', response);
                },
                error: function () {
                    console.log('coudn\'t upload');
                }
            });
            //return false;
        })
```

I think the problem is that by the time I capture response in jquery, multer hasnt uploaded the file so I have no or blank response in ajax. I am not sure how to fix this.

Comment: Did you check the network tab to see what you actually got as a response? jQuery attempts to parse the response, so that may be why it becomes empty.

Comment: I get the correct response in network tab.

Comment: Try setting the accepts header on the request to be of the file type you expect in response.

Comment: That wont solve it as I tried that already. I think the problem is that by the time I capture response in jquery, multer hasnt uploaded the file so I have no or blank response in ajax. I am not sure how to fix this.

Comment: That seems strange. Multer should not call `next()` before it saves the file on disk.

Answer (score 0):

```
app.post('/', upload.any(), function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.files);
    var image = req.files;
    console.log(image);
    res.send(image); // this should come to jQuery response object
    res.end();  // !!! - note this!
});
```

You have to add `res.end()` to finalize the response.